# How to remove HDRI background in lookdev mode?

Tags: hdri

How to remove HDRI background in lookdev mode? I'm using Blender 2.9.

Answer (score 2):

Very easy. Go to shading tab and set the world opcity to 0.[image]

Comment: Aaaaah. thank you very much! I figured it was something simple and obvious like that.  Much appreciated!